# Первая в стеке активность[Android]

Tags: android, activity

**Доброго времени суток!**

Думаю, каждый "более-менее" Android-разработчик видел данную схему:

[image]

это стек активностей. Рисунок демонстрирует, что происходит при запуске новой активности. Так вот, при исследовании одного Android-приложения, я столкнулся с проблемой. Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо как-то получить имя самой привилегированной активности(та, что на верхушке стека). Но вот как это сделать? Нужно просто получить имя той активности, которая в данный момент поверх всех. Буду рад любой помощи( любому способу ).

**Спасибо)**

Comment: а зачем такое может понадобится?

Answer (score 2):

[Ссылка на пример](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/).

**Updated:**

Добавил реализацию метода для получения имени верхней `Activity` в указанном приложении:

```
public String getTopActivityName(String appPackage) {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (final ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (task.topActivity.getPackageName().equals(appPackage)) {
            return task.topActivity.getClassName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Единственный аргумент — `appPackage` — как не сложно догадаться, это package name приложения (тот, что в AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: Да, это хороший пример, если делать это требуется из своего приложения, но у меня другая ситуация: приложения запущено, вот его главная активность на вершине стека. Её-то и нужно получить.

Comment: Ну так и берите нужный `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo` из возвращаемой коллекции.

Comment: Добавил реализацию метода.